# Mosquitto.h does not define "struct mosquitto" contents

Tags: mosquitto, libmosquitto

As far as I understood, when client connects, I must check for session being persistent, and if it is not, perform subscribe to the topics of interest. I am using Mosquitto version 1.5.

I did not find a way to check for this property using API calls, but found out there's `clean_session` boolean field in the `struct mosquitto`. But when I try to access it this way:

```
void my_connect_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int result)
{
    log("Connected, session persistency",(int)(mosq->clean_session));
```

I get error *dereferencing pointer to incomplete type*. It appears to be normal as soon as `mosquitto.h` does NOT have definition of the fields within `struct mosquitto`. The file called `mosquitto_internal.h` does have it, but it seems it is not designed to be included into the application project.

What is wrong here?

**Update (after @hardillb comment):** (1) I did not find documentation saying that `clean_session` in the mosquitto struct is the same I pass to `mosquitto_new`; (2) the documentation [here](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-3-client-broker-connection-establishment/) says

> The CONNACK message contains two data entries:
>
> - The session present flag
> - A connect return code

And it is logical that "session present flag" would be somewhere in the connect callback data or in mosquitto struct itself. Therefore I guessed that `clean_session` in the struct is the value returned by the connect function. Next, same source says:

> The session present flag tells the client whether the broker already
> has a persistent session available from previous interactions with the
> client. When a client connects with Clean Session set to true, the
> session present flag is always false because there is no session
> available. If a client connects with Clean Session set to false, there
> are two possibilities: If session information is available for the
> clientId. and the broker has stored session information, **the session
> present flag is true**.

Where is this `session_present` flag - so that application knows current connection is continuation of previous and does not re-subscribe to same topics?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? the `mosq->clean_session` will always hold the value of the `clean_session` value you passed to `mosquitto_new` it won't change based on any response from the broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/3cbe805e71ac41a2a20cc9b2ea6b3b619f49554a/lib/callbacks.c#L32) code it implies you should be using the `mosquitto_connect_with_flags_callback_set()` rather than `mosquitto_connect_callback_set()`

And passing a callback function pointer that takes an extra `int` field at the end of the args.

The int field will hold the CONNACK [flags](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349255) (which will basically be 0 or 1)

It does look like that callback is missing from the [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/libmosquitto-3.html) page.

Comment: Better doc here https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html